# Zend Context Switch with Layout

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, context-switch

I'm using context switching within Zend to display HTML via XHR in a dialog.

Throughout my application I load CSS/ script files based on the module/ controller I am in; an example being while in the View controller of the User module, my application would load the css/user/view.css script.

However, since I am using context switches, my metahead (part of my layout) is not rendering (for obvious reasons), so only the styles of the current page from which the XHR request was made from are available.

Is there a nice, clean way I can pull in styles for the module/controller on the XHR end-point?

Thanks

Comment: And you never know for certain on the requesting page that you will be making use of the fragment?  Seems like only two options.  Make your partial HTML stand alone with inline styles, or load up full CSS (both sheets) on the requesting page to ensure it will always be available should you need it.